# Real part of complex sequence converge to real part of limit

Tags: complex-analysis

If $(z_n)$ is a sequence of complex numbers that converge to $z$, is it true that the real part $\text{Re}(z_n)$ converges to $\text{Re(z)}$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, because
$$
0\le |\operatorname{Re} z_n - \operatorname{Re} z |\le |z_n -z|.
$$